# Lenovo laptop temperatures while gaming

Tags: laptop, overheating, lenovo-laptop, cpu-temperature, laptop-cooler

I have been a little concerned lately because my laptop temperatures are a bit suspicious, I have a Lenovo Y400 and i've been monitoring my temperatures with HWMonitor and I found out that while I'm gaming the CPU temperature rise up to 80°C (they are between 70-80) and the GPU up to 68°C and while I'm using it for web browsing the CPU registers a temperature between 50-60°C and the GPU stays at 45°C. I'm concerned about my laptop and I will love if anyone could help me or tell me if my temperatures are fine because sincerely I have no idea.

Thanks

Comment: For a laptop those temperatures are common. That model isn't made for gaming. Hence the cooling isn't as powerful as on gaming laptops for example. Ambient temperatures are a factor too. What are the Idle temperatures?

Comment: The ambient temperature is about 25 to 30°C and for the CPU the idle temp. is from 40-50°C and the GPU is 39°C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These temperatures are common for your laptop, and given that gaming is an intensive task for any machine, it is normal that the temperature rises.

*Although there is nothing more to say and it has been said in the comments too, I've posted this as an answer, so you can mark this question as answered.*